# Utlization of services points in pedestrian flow simulation in anylogic

Tags: java, anylogic

I am working on the pedestrian flow model and I want to know the utilization of the "service points" in the service block.
I have tried using the services.servicePoint(1).statsUtilization.mean() but this doesnt seem to be a valid code as I am not able to call the service points as I have done in my previous models to call "other resources" and its utilization.

is there any alternate solution?

Answer (score 0):

There's no utilization statistics for an individual service point, but what I would do is:

- create a some sort of collection that will have the information of each service point (you can use a class with the info on the service point and utilization times and create an arraylist of that class, or maybe a LinkedHashMap with a key as the service point and the value as the time of utilization of the service point)
- In the pedService block you can access the service point on begin service and begin enter.. you will use the time it takes there to save that value to your collection
- Then you calculate the utilization by yourself according to your conditions (maybe you have shifts)

So not so simple, but possible